# Function to escape quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, search, escaping, elasticsearch

to start off, I don't do much JavaScript and am a complete newbie at it, now that's out of the way.. I've got a slight problem I'm trying to escape quotes from users inputs in my search app:

```
function getQString()
{
var query_str = 'q=' + $('input[name=q]').val().trim();
return  query_str;
}
```

This is done as a method within a gsp file, is there something equivalent to .escape() in JavaScript?

This query is later sent to elastic search and gives me hell due to the quotes especially input like a"b..

I'm using ES 0.20.6

Comment: `$('input[name=q]').val().trim().replace(/\"/g,'');`

Comment: Try `'q='+encodeURIComponent($('input[name=q]').val().trim())`.

Comment: encodeURIComponent is the right way to pass data in url. Escaping quotes on client is not necessary. To avoid sql-injections you still need to escape it on server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
query_str = query_str.replace(/"/g, '\\\"');
```

..will result in; `"` to `\"`

**OR**

```
query_str = query_str.replace(/"/g, '\\\\\"');
```

..will result in; `"` to `\\"`, which will make a printed quotation still be escaped to `\"`.

This code;

```
var test = 'asdasd " asd a "';

console.log(test.replace(/"/g, '\\\"'));
console.log(test.replace(/"/g, '\\\\\"'));
```

..outputs;

```
asdasd \" asd a \"
asdasd \\" asd a \\"
```

You might adjust the replacement based on how your final interpreter reads the string and prints it out.

Comment: `\"` means `"` in a JS string.

Comment: you don't need to escape double quotes in single quotes '"' is a proper code

Comment: Maybe I read wrong; doesn't the OP want to add escapes to the quotations? Maybe I misread, my apologies may that be the case.

Comment: You now have an escaped slash character (which means "a slash") followed by an escaped quote character (which means the same as a literal quote character).

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give it a whirl and see the outcome.

Comment: "'".replace(/'/g, '"') will replace any single quote by double quote. However I beleive OP don't need to do it.

Comment: Then it would require 5 slashes to escape the slashes twice, making the later-used string \\", and thus printing out \" in the end. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tommi no I don't need to escape single quotes, ElasticSearch can handle those pretty well.

Comment: Hmm, Still seems to hiccup, it does escape the double quotes now, but Lucene doesn't seem to like it. I guess replacing double quotes with single ones would be the other way? Would that look something like: query_str = query_str.replace(/"/g, '\\'');
i.e: h"i --> h'i

Comment: For Lucene double quotes is a special characters for defining phrase tokens. It's better to replace it with something neutral (for example, space, but it depends on what Anaylyzer/Tokenizer used by your engine). Actually, default Lucene parser will fail to parse query with quotes mismatch. Here is good reference about query syntax. Try to avoid/escape any special chars or use it wisely http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html

Comment: FYI, your replacement string only has to be `'\\"'` -- because the 'other' type of quote doesn't need to be escaped in a quoted string.  Doesn't hurt, but it may get confusing.  The triple slash is required if using the same type of quote `'\\\''` or `"\\\""`.